# Git + Jira + Visual Studio - Code review practice for large volume of Git commits against a particular Jira ticket

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio, github, jira

I am about to start performing code review for some of the Jira tickets. Few of them are having more than 200 Git commits against them, and manually opening each commit and performing review does not seem to be an ideal option.

Developers in my company are associating each commit with a Jira ticket, and its very much part of the process, so there is no possibility of missing any commit.

What I really need is to know the consolidated list of files which are added/ removed/ changed within all the commits of a particular Jira ticket.

Can anyone please guide what should be the best way to achieve this? Also, Is there any tool available for this?

Comment: Any help on this would be much appreciated!